# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Product')

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, next.js

I couldn't find what is the problem or where should I look. I can send request with postman but my model file gives me this error
I have 2 file in my models documment user.js working well but product.js gives this kind of Error.

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Product')

```
import mongoose, { Schema, models } from "mongoose";

const productSchema = new Schema(
    {
        title: String,
        description: String,
        stock: Number,
    },
    {
        timestamps: true, 
    }
);
const Product = mongoose.models.Product || mongoose.model('Product', productSchema); //gives error at this line.

export default Product;
```

[image: error page]

I was trying to create a model for MongoDB. One of my model working well but other one not.

Comment: Is `mongoose.models` defined?

Comment: at where? in my models/product.js file? Do I need this beacuse my other model file working well

Comment: try this
`const Product = mongoose.models?.Product || mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);`

Comment: Giving this TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'models')

Answer (score 0):

try `export const Product = model('Product', productSchema);`
use **model**

Answer (score 0):

The code below should work for you:

```
import mongoose, { Schema } from "mongoose";

const productSchema = new Schema(
    {
        title: String,
        description: String,
        stock: Number,
    },
    {
        timestamps: true, 
    }
);

export const Product = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
```

Import this model when you want to use it:

```
import { Product } from 'path/of/your/schema/'

const product = await Product.create({
  title: "test",
  description: "test description",
  stock: "50",
});
```

Comment: I imported already actually  and thats not the solution. Here is my whole repository https://github.com/nazlicansahin/management if you want you can see my whole project

Answer (score 0):

just replace `const Product = mongoose.models.Product || mongoose.model('Product', productSchema)` to `export const Product = model('Product', productSchema);`